# impacts of converting TIN to GRID

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, convert, format, esri-grid-format

My DEM comes in TIN-format so that i will have to convert it to GRID to be able to analyse it with Spatial Analyst.

Will there be any inaccuracies to my data from converting TIN to GRID?

Answer (score 2):

The [ArcGIS online help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00q900000077000000) says:

> Because interpolation of the input TIN surface occurs at regular intervals, some loss of information in the output raster should be expected. How well the raster represents the TIN is dependent on the resolution of the raster and the degree and interval of TIN surface variation. Generally, as the resolution is increased, the output raster more closely represents the TIN surface. Because the raster is a cell structure, it cannot maintain the hard and soft breakline edges that may be present in the TIN.

So if there are breaklines present in the TIN, these won't be maintained in the GRID you're converting to. However the conversion simply takes the TIN's value at each grid cell center and assigns this to the cell. The conversion won't contain any inaccuraries, but the precision of the output GRID strongly depends on how you choose your GRID resolution.

Comment: Thank you! Since I'm told that my DEM has the resolution 1x1 m, i would probably try to make my GRID 1x1 m, too. Right...?

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't take a smaller cellsize as this would imply that your grid is more precise than it is in truth.

Comment: Are the data truly irregular, or is the DEM just regular grid data in a TIN file format?

Comment: Good question... How would I ceck that? (Sorry I'm quite a beginner with GIS!)

Comment: @chris3o12 you can tell by zooming in on the TIN. If the TIN's geometry is very regular (straight angles, blocky structure) it's probably built from a grid.